# Trapping only exceptions that occur when an active directory user already exists using the New-QADUser cmdlet?

Tags: active-directory, powershell

If I only want to trap an exception when a user already exists, what type of Exception should I trap?

for instance:

```
 [UserAlreadyExistsException]
 trap{
    #forget about it....
 }
 [AnyOtherException]
 trap{
    #PANIC!
 }
 $newUser = New-QADUser -name $line.UserID -ParentContainer 'OU=Symetra,DC=CI3DOMAIN,DC=local' -samAccountName $line.UserID -UserPassword 'p' -DisplayName $line.APPROVER -Department $line.Department -Description "$approver from $department" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

### Update!

I was just notified [here](http://activeroles.inside.quest.com/thread.jspa?threadID=15100&tstart=0) that the exception thrown is `system.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesComException`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Try, Catch block like the following.

```
try
{
   New-ADUser "FAKEACCOUNT"
}
catch [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityAlreadyExistsException]
{
   #forget about it....
}
catch
{
   #PANIC!
}
```

Note: I'm not positive the New-QADUser cmdlet throws the same exception, but the above code works for the New-ADUser cmdlet.

This link may help you decipher the specifics of your situation: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adpowershell/archive/2009/03/25/error-reporting-in-active-directory-powershell.aspx

Comment: Yeah I didn't realize that the trap syntax was from the first version of PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

I use this function to test for AD objects:

```
function Test-QADObject {
 [CmdletBinding()]
 param(
      [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true)]
      [System.String]
      $Identity
 )
(Get-QADObject $Identity -DontUseDefaultIncludedProperties `
-WarningAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue `
-SizeLimit 1) -ne $null
```

}

It's from [here](http://dmitrysotnikov.wordpress.com) but I can't find the direct link.